# How do we go about designing for Touch based desktops & normal desktops?

Tags: usability, touch-screen, ux-field, desktop-application

Imagine you are getting a new project in manufacturing domain. Requirement is an Enterprise application which needs to be designed for user groups who will use it in office/factory floor. User uses desktops and touch based laptops. How do we go about designing for them. What are the main points to be considered?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have given enough context, but from my little experience

1. **Design for fingers, not for mouse.** for example don't use design-patterns like hover at all
2. **Keep all action-based controls like buttons etc on right side.** Laptops are around 12-15 inches wide and if someone has to use it standing upright, it will be difficult for them to use 2 hands. So design for the right hand.
3. If the app has features like serial data entry work which has to be done over and over again, then ensure that **user should be able to do it faster with time**. Ensure that user will be able to work with keyboard alone without positioning the pointer on the screen at all since it will disrupt his flow of work.
4. **Don't use too many technical names which are not used by them on daily basis**. App should be intuitive enough to use without training.
5. Handle errors in such a way that you inform the user about how to correct it. **Don't design error handling in such a way that customer support is assumed**.
6. **Design a tour guide for the app** (include videos and images) so that user can check it out if there is any doubt rather than asking customer support.

I don't think this is an exhaustive list, but hopefully this will help you get started.

Comment: I'm confused about #2...why would standing affect which hand one can use?

Comment: @DA01 if you are using a touch-based laptop while standing, it will be difficult to use it with both hands, you will naturally be using one hand for tapping and one for support. Why don't you pickup a touch-based laptop (or a tablet in landscape mode) while standing and see which hand you will use for support and which one for tapping? won't you be more comfortable if the controls like button, checkboxes, etc are on the right side rather than on left side?

Comment: I have friends who are left handed... They are more comfortable with the left side...

Comment: @Majo0od which actually proves the point I am making to design for right hand since only 12% people on the planet are left handed http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/science/lefty-righty-here-astonishing-statistics-4757193.

Comment: My point is, you're designing from your own perspective instead of a universal perspective.

Comment: @Majo0od I am designing for majority perspective (and a huge one of 88%) which is not far from what apple does http://9to5mac.com/2014/09/09/a-look-at-apples-reachability-one-hand-mode-for-larger-iphone-6-video/

Comment: I'm sorry, but "what apple does" is not a valid point to me: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/86535/should-ios-native-app-be-distinctly-different-than-the-responsive-websites-mobi

Comment: @Majo0od that's okay. Product design cannot be about catering to universal preferences anyways. It is about what you think is right for the users, given that you understand your users enough. I think designing for right handed people caters to most of my scenarios, so I would do that. And I am saying this without knowing about how big is left-hand population of the OP's target user base is. If the OP feels that majority of his target user base is left handed, then he should keep controls on left hand side.

Comment: @Majo0od Amidst all this, OP shouldn't confuse that contention is between designing for left vs right hand, not whether to design for his/her preferable hand at all.

Comment: @gurvinder372 If you're saying one has to hold a laptop while using it, then yes, that makes sense...one hand operation. That said, holding and using a touch based laptop would be really annoying...after all, that's what tablets are for.

Answer (score 1):

adding to what gurudinver372 said, also consider the ease of touch depending on the area of the screen. Meaning some areas of the screen are easier to touch than others

[image]

Comment: I'm not too sure I'm convinced with the laptop's touch easiness levels. You'd think that all of it is easy because laptops are normally standing on something leaving both hands free?